# Are there accessible videos of past International Space Development Conferences?

Tags: video, nss

I was browsing through the old ISDC archives, and I noticed several topics and speakers that I might be interested in seeing. Are videos of past ISDCs made available somewhere? All I could find was a couple of keynote speeches and some clips from the 2013 and 2015 conferences. Would I need to make a request from the [National Space Society (NSS)](http://www.nss.org/)?

Comment: At the most recent conference only some of the talks were filmed. Many talked i really enjoyed weren't filmed. Availability of volunteers was mentioned as a reason, as i recall.

Comment: @kimholder Interesting, that is good to know. That may be the best answer here, Kim, if you care to turn it into one.

Comment: I'm actually hoping for a much better answer... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [this collection of videos](https://www.youtube.com/user/NationalSpaceSociety/playlists?sort=dd&view=50&shelf_id=4) on the NSS's YouTube channel, taken by attendees. They search for such uploaded videos and make them more accessible this way. Right now there are about 150 such videos.

However even that is only a smattering of the talks that occurred. ISDCs are huge events, I'd estimate the 25 videos of the most recent one represents maybe 15% of the talks that occurred. Most of those talks were not filmed by the NSS. There were usually 5 or 6 talks happening at any one time, and there weren't enough volunteers to film properly. Proper cameras and often lights were set up in cases where filming was done, and then carted off to other talks. There is no official record of a lot of great talks.

The archivist has the complete records of many past conferences, which used to be officially recorded and later sold on DVDs. Apparently there are legal issues with uploading these to a public venue. If you are interested in getting particular talks, try contacting him through their main email: nsshq@nss.org - and put it attn: Dale Amon.